# Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $m>0$ with nonzero coefficients. Prove that $P(x)=\cos(x)$ can have exactly $n$ roots.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, roots

The problem is...

> Let $m$, $n$ be any positive integers. Prove that for each $m$ and $n$, there always exists a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $m$ with non-zero real coefficients such that $P(x)=\cos(x)$ has exactly $n$ roots in $\mathbb{R}$ (without counting multiplicities).

I proved it for even $m$ and $n\le\frac{m}{2}$ by letting $P(x)$ be tangent to $(2k\pi,1)$, $(1\le k\le n).$
And I think it is true because it holds for $m=1$, and $P(x)$ can become similar to a linear function by making the coefficient of $x^{k}(k>1)$ very close to 0. But I can't find a solid proof for this. I first tried it with Rolle's theorem. For several tens of minutes, I tried to prove this with Taylor's theorem, but I couldn't find any clue how to prove it because of the error term. I also tried and failed to find the proof on internet.

I would highly appreciate any help for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am confused. For $m=1$, $P(x)=a_0+a_1x$. How can then $P(x)=\cos(x)$ be true?

Comment: For $m=1$, there exists $a_{0}$, $a_{1}$ such that $a_{0}+a_{1}x=\cos x$ has $n$ roots for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: Use the intermediate value theorem instead. This is mostly a theorem about continuity, not differentiability. The exception is that if $n$ is odd, you will need one tangential intersection somewhere. For a fixed $n$, solve it first for $m=1$. This solution will have its roots in some bounded interval $[-a,a]$. You can use those bounds to establish a range of variation on that solution that will not change the root count. Choose your higher-degree polynomials to remain in that variation in $[-a,a]$. For odd $n$ you also need the polynomials to preserve value and tangent at the tangential root.